# Hat Dash cheat-punishment music won't connect to YouTube

Tags: bug, hat-dash

<sup>Apologies:  I had to try to cheat to get this error</sup>

If you get caught cheating at Hat Dash, it's supposed to say "You have been caught cheating" and then show a "See here for more info" button  (which will redirect you to [10 hours Rick Roll'd + epic sax guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ohbr90cKDc)).  But it caught me in the act, I clicked the link and it showed this:

[image]

Can we fix that?  The punishment for hoodwinking Sparkles should be severe, not gray and sax-free.

Comment: It's you, not us; the link works fine.

Comment: ??? you WANT to be rick-rolled?

Comment: It could be your internet that is the problem. If you check your connection and then reload the page, it might work.

Comment: @JoeKerr I tried that many times (or I wouldn't have posted the question).  I disconnected/re-connected, cleared cache and cookies.  It redirects to the link just fine in `/unicorn`.  It still doesn't work in Hat Dash.

Comment: Did you mean "shouldn't" or "should"?